# How to concat in MySql Insert Before Trigger with Select Statement of Auto Increment ID

Tags: php, mysql, select, triggers

I have four columns in a table (Names: prdRevise, prdCode, prdMfgNmbr, prdID). I am inserting values in first two columns through PHP and want to generate prdID with other three. prdMfgNmbr is autoincrement which is currently inserting '0' on new.prdMfgNmbr's place. Below is the trigger I am using.

```
set new.prdId = concat(new.prdCode, new.prdRevise, new.prdMfgNmbr)
```

following Query is giving me upcoming Auto_Increment Value. . dont know how to use it in triger.

```
SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT`
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'labautomation'
AND   TABLE_NAME   = 'prdmfg';
```

Comment: You cannot expect an auto increment field to have appropriate value (e.g. the inserted id) **before** the insertion! If you changed the trigger from before insert to after insert, it will work.

Comment: Updating a new record is not allowed in after triger. .  .

Comment: OK, you mixed up the concept of tables and field names in the 1st sentence of the question. Perhaps you should correct that. I thought the trigger would insert a piece of new data into another table.

Comment: In this case you cannot use a trigger, but you can still use a stored procedure to do the task for you. The stored procedure would first insert the new record with prdCode, prdRevise received as parameters. Then it would query the newly inserted prdMfgNmbr and update the prdId based on the other 3 columns' value.

Comment: Can u please guide me how to do that. . . I dont know much about store procedures.

Comment: Give it a try and then we will help you if you get stuck.

Comment: Getting nowhere . . . . Help plz

Answer (score -1):

I figured out a way to do the thing at front end in PHP:

```
$qry5="SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT`FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'labautomation'AND   TABLE_NAME   ='prdmfg'";          
        $qrprId=mysql_query($qry5);
        $qrMfgNmbr =  mysql_fetch_assoc($qrprId); 
        $newqrMfgNmbr=$qrMfgNmbr['AUTO_INCREMENT'];
```

after getting the value I used it with other values from farm to send it into DB in prdID column. But Store procedure thing will still be appreciated.

Comment: This is what you **MUST NOT** do! Concurrent queries may get the same value!